# Solving modular linear congruences for large numbers

Tags: python, math, linear-programming, modulo

I'm looking for a better algorithm than one I found on stackoverflow to handle 4096 byte numbers, i'm hitting a maximum recursion depth.

Code from stackoverlow post, taken from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59505761/16490627):

```
def linear_congruence(a, b, m):
    if b == 0:
        return 0

    if a < 0:
        a = -a
        b = -b

    b %= m
    while a > m:
        a -= m

    return (m * linear_congruence(m, -b, a) + b) // a
```

This works fine for smaller numbers, for example:

```
In [167]: pow_mod(8261, 63, 4033)                                                                                                                             
63 1 8261 4033
31 195 1728 4033
15 2221 1564 4033
7 1231 2098 4033
3 1518 1601 4033
1 2452 2246 4033
0 2147 3266 4033
Out[167]: 2147

And the linear congruence works:

linear_congruence(8261, 3266, 4033):
2147
```

But i hit maximum recursion depth with larger numbers. Is there a better algorithm or non recursive algorithm of the linear_congruence algorithm i provided?

Based on  Eric Postpischil's remark, i wrote the pseudocode from the wikipedia entry and created a very fast linear congruence algorithm utilizing the method from here: http://gauss.math.luc.edu/greicius/Math201/Fall2012/Lectures/linear-congruences.article.pdf .

This works nicely on pows with a powers of 2-1, to get the answer. I'm looking into how offsetting from this changes the answer and hope to incorporate it to work for those answers as well, but for now, i have what i need since i'm working with powers of 2 -1 for y in pow(x, y, z):

```
 def fastlinearcongruencex(powx, divmodx, N, withstats=False):
   x, y, z = egcditerx(powx, N, withstats)
   if x > 1:
      powx//=x
      divmodx//=x
      N//=x
      if withstats == True:
        print(f"powx = {powx}, divmodx = {divmodx}, N = {N}")
      x, y, z = egcditerx(powx, N)
      if withstats == True:
        print(f"x = {x}, y = {y}, z = {z}")
   answer = (y*divmodx)%N
   if withstats == True:
      print(f"answer = {answer}")
   return answer

def egcditerx(a, b, withstats=False):
  s = 0
  r = b
  old_s = 1
  old_r = a
  while r!= 0:
    quotient = old_r // r
    old_r, r = r, old_r - quotient * r
    old_s, s = s, old_s - quotient * s
    if withstats == True:
      print(f"quotient = {quotient}, old_r = {old_r}, r = {r}, old_s = {old_s}, s = {s}")
  if b != 0:
    bezout_t = quotient = (old_r - old_s * a) // b
    if withstats == True:
      print(f"bezout_t = {bezout_t}")
  else:
    bezout_t = 0
  if withstats == True:
    print("Bézout coefficients:", (old_s, bezout_t))
    print("greatest common divisor:", old_r)
  return old_r, old_s, bezout_t
```

It even works instantaneously on 4096 byte numbers which is great:

```
In [19036]: rpowxxxwithbitlength(1009,offset=0, withstats=True, withx=True, withbl=True)                                                                  
63 1 272 1009
31 272 327 1009
15 152 984 1009
7 236 625 1009
3 186 142 1009
1 178 993 1009
0 179 256 1009
Out[19036]: (179, 256, True, 272)

In [19037]: fastlinearcongruencex(272,256,1009)                                                                                                           
Out[19037]: 179
```

Thank you Eric for pointing out what this was, i wrote an extremely fast linear congruence algorithm utilizing egcd and the procedure from the pdf above. If any stackoverflowers need a fast algorithm, please point them to this one. I also learned that congruence is always maintained when the pow(x,y,z) has a y off of the powers of 2-1.   I will look into this further to see if an offset change exists to keep the answers intact and will follow up in the future if found.

Comment: Do you know in advance that `a` is relatively prime to `m`? If not, how do you want to handle cases involving multiple solutions, or no solutions?

Comment: If i could get multiple solutions that would be great, i have noticed that it's not 100% so i'm glad to hear there are multiple solutions. I'm only using this for numbers that are pow mod, so i haven't seen a case of no solutions so i'm not sure how i would want to handle those, maybe just get no answer. Right now, if i don't get the right answer, i do the next number above and usually that works.

Comment: Also, i don't know that a is relatively prime to m. I'm using an algorithim to generate a, and working on a personal educational math project to see if i can formulate numbers that i can predict the last modulus x. i know, that sounds impossible, but it's a fun project, and i'm having fun working on something that sounds impossible :-)

Comment: Rewrite the code as a loop, not a recursive call. This is the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) and should not be written with recursion.

Comment: The source was most likely [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59505761/1377097).

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Thank you for letting me know this could be done with EGCD, i wrote an extremely fast linear congruence algorithm that i think will be beneficial to future stackoverflow questions for solving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Python 3.8 or later, you can do everything you need to with a very small number of lines of code.

First some mathematics: I'm assuming that you want to solve `ax = b (mod m)` for an integer `x`, given integers `a`, `b` and `m`. I'm also assuming that `m` is positive.

The first thing you need to compute is the greatest common divisor `g` of `a` and `m`. There are two cases:

- if `b` is not a multiple of `g`, then the congruence has no solutions (if `ax + my = b` for some integers `x` and `y`, then any common divisor of `a` and `m` must also be a divisor of `b`)
- if `b` *is* a multiple of `g`, then the congruence is exactly equivalent to `(a/g)x = (b/g) (mod (m/g))`. Now `a/g` and `m/g` are relatively prime, so we can compute an inverse to `a/g` modulo `m/g`. Multiplying that inverse by `b/g` gives a solution, and the general solution can be obtained by adding an arbitrary multiple of `m/g` to that solution.

Python's [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#module-math) module has had a [`gcd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) function since Python 3.5, and the built-in [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) function can be used to compute modular inverses since Python 3.8.

Putting it all together, here's some code. First a function that finds the general solution, or raises an exception if no solution exists. If it succeeds, it returns two integers. The first gives a particular solution; the second gives the modulus that provides the general solution.

```
def solve_linear_congruence(a, b, m):
    """ Describe all solutions to ax = b  (mod m), or raise ValueError. """
    g = math.gcd(a, m)
    if b % g:
        raise ValueError("No solutions")
    a, b, m = a//g, b//g, m//g
    return pow(a, -1, m) * b % m, m
```

And then some driver code, to demonstrate how to use the above.

```
def print_solutions(a, b, m):
    print(f"Solving the congruence: {a}x = {b}  (mod {m})")
    try:
        x, mx = solve_linear_congruence(a, b, m)
    except ValueError:
        print("No solutions")
    else:
        print(f"Particular solution: x = {x}")
        print(f"General solution: x = {x}  (mod {mx})")
```

Example use:

```
>>> print_solutions(272, 256, 1009)
Solving the congruence: 272x = 256  (mod 1009)
Particular solution: x = 179
General solution: x = 179  (mod 1009)
>>> print_solutions(98, 105, 1001)
Solving the congruence: 98x = 105  (mod 1001)
Particular solution: x = 93
General solution: x = 93  (mod 143)
>>> print_solutions(98, 107, 1001)
Solving the congruence: 98x = 107  (mod 1001)
No solutions
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this out in a VM as i don't have 3.8, but that is an awesome addition. This works great

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that for some reason the linear congruence equations you'll be 'attacking' come up 'empty' (no solutions) often enough to be a design criteria for your algorithm.

It turns out that you can use just (with any real overhead) the residue operations to answer that binary question -

> There exist solutions XOR There are no solutions

This might have utility in cryptography; see also the [abstract](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285648335_Introduction_of_the_Residue_Number_Arithmetic_Logic_Unit_With_Brief_Computational_Complexity_Analysis),

*Introduction of the Residue Number Arithmetic Logic Unit

With Brief Computational Complexity Analysis*

Once you determine that a solution exist, you can use back substitution
and the ALU to determine a solution.

Also, you'll have calculated the gcd(a,m) and can construct the coefficients of Bézout's identity
(*if* you need them).

Following is python program that incorporates the above ideas; it calculates the minimal solution when it exists and prints out Bézout's identity.

```
test_data = [ \
(32,12,82), \
(9,3,23), \
(17,41,73), \
(227,1,2011), \
(25,15,29), \
(2,22,71), \
(7,10,21), \
(124,58,900), \
(46, 12, 240), \
]

for lc in test_data:
    LC = lc
    back_sub_List = []
    while True:
        back_sub_List.append(LC)
        n_mod_a = LC[2] % LC[0]
        if n_mod_a == 0:
            break
        LC = (n_mod_a, -LC[1] % LC[0], LC[0])
    gcd_of_a0_n0 = LC[0]
    if LC[1] % LC[0] != 0:
        print(f"No solution          for {back_sub_List[0][0]}x = {back_sub_List[0][1]} (mod {back_sub_List[0][2]})")
    else:
        k = 0
        for LC in back_sub_List[::-1]: # solve with back substitution
            a,b,m = LC
            k = (b + k*m) // a         # optimize calculation since the remainder is zero?
        print(f"The minimal solution for {back_sub_List[0][0]}x = {back_sub_List[0][1]} (mod {back_sub_List[0][2]}) is equal to {k}")
    # get bezout
    S = [1,0]
    T = [0,1]
    for LC in back_sub_List:    
        a,b,n = LC
        q = n // a
        s = S[0] - q * S[1]
        S = [S[1], s]
        t = T[0] - q * T[1]
        T = [T[1], t]
    print(f"  Bézout's identity:     ({S[0]})({lc[2]}) + ({T[0]})({lc[0]}) = {gcd_of_a0_n0}")
```

**PROGRAM OUTPUT**

```
The minimal solution for 32x = 12 (mod 82) is equal to 26
  Bézout's identity:     (-7)(82) + (18)(32) = 2
The minimal solution for 9x = 3 (mod 23) is equal to 8
  Bézout's identity:     (2)(23) + (-5)(9) = 1
The minimal solution for 17x = 41 (mod 73) is equal to 11
  Bézout's identity:     (7)(73) + (-30)(17) = 1
The minimal solution for 227x = 1 (mod 2011) is equal to 1320
  Bézout's identity:     (78)(2011) + (-691)(227) = 1
The minimal solution for 25x = 15 (mod 29) is equal to 18
  Bézout's identity:     (-6)(29) + (7)(25) = 1
The minimal solution for 2x = 22 (mod 71) is equal to 11
  Bézout's identity:     (1)(71) + (-35)(2) = 1
No solution          for 7x = 10 (mod 21)
  Bézout's identity:     (0)(21) + (1)(7) = 7
No solution          for 124x = 58 (mod 900)
  Bézout's identity:     (4)(900) + (-29)(124) = 4
The minimal solution for 46x = 12 (mod 240) is equal to 42
  Bézout's identity:     (-9)(240) + (47)(46) = 2
```

Comment: I've recognized that to compute Bézout's coefficients a computer algorithm should use exact integer division. Of interest: In 1993 Tudor Jebelean wrote two papers (1) A Generalization of the Binary GCD Algorithm (2) An Algorithm for Exact Division